# Ics file - Outlook Calendar working - Google Calendar not so much?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

Im using a third party .ics file to update activity in APPsheet via ca google calandar
I am not getting calendar updates in Google calendar just original content , no cancelations or updates.

I tried the exact same link in Outlook, and it works?

However there is no direct link from Appsheet to Outlook, so i am stuck with Google calendar?

Do I have to change settings in Google/chrome/calendar.
Is the .ics code missing something for Google cal to work.

1. BEGIN:VCALENDAR
2. VERSION:2.0
3. PRODID:-//XXXXX//iCal Feed//EN
4. CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
5. METHOD:PUBLISH
6. BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
7. TZID:Europe/London
8. X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/London
9. BEGIN:STANDARD
10. DTSTART:20231029T020000
11. TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
12. TZOFFSETTO:+0000
13. RDATE:20241027T020000
14. TZNAME:GMT
15. END:STANDARD
16. BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
17. DTSTART:20230326T010000
18. TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
19. TZOFFSETTO:+0100
20. RDATE:20240331T010000
21. TZNAME:BST
22. END:DAYLIGHT
23. END:VTIMEZONE
24. BEGIN:VEVENT
25. X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
26. URL;VALUE=URI:https://XXXX/bookings_detail.asp?bookingID=123456
27. DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20221125T000000
28. DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20221209T000000
29. ORGANIZER;CN=XXXX:MAILTO:XXXX.co.uk
30. LOCATION:hol let name
31. UID:B6FB62D81DAA3340F43FF44112705D3423D51234@xxxx
32. X-WR-CALNAME:Cottage bookings
33. DTSTAMP:20231201T000000
34. SEQUENCE:0
35. SUMMARY: Booking ref 10xxxx xxxxxx
36. DESCRIPTION: 200 characters long
37. PRIORITY:3
38. END:VEVENT

Comment: I believe this Stack Overflow post would answer your question. Can you confirm? [Google doesn't sync my subscribed ICS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560457)